# Need help to understand a shell script to set gpio pin on Raspberry Pi

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

I have a script for a Raspberry Pi but I don't understand what is going on. I do know that its purpose should be to set GPIO19 to High, since the initial state after booting is Low or undefined respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash    
for pin in 19; do
/usr/bin/env gpio export ${pin} out
chown -R pi /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pin}
chmod -R g+w /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pin} done
chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem
chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

I am not very familiar with Shell scripts, Raspbian and Raspberry Pi in general, so I would appreciate a line by line explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this script works? Not sure why a for loop is used as there is only one iteration on 19. The env command doesn't look correct either

Comment: @RamanSailopal The script seems to work since it is in use for some time now. And the `for` loop was probably intended to set multiple pins within the script, but in the end only GPIO19 was necessary. The script was then never changed accordingly.